# Liferay Scopes: Web Content Display & Page Display

Tags: scope, liferay

I am starting to use Scopes on a Site using `Liferay CE 6.1 GA1`. I have one Site, and two scopes within this site: `S1` and `S2`.

I am facing two issues:

1. When trying to display the Web Content that I added in `S1` through the Control Panel, the Web Content Display portlet doesn't display anything. I can select the correct Web Content when selecting scope in portlet configuration as `S1`, but when I save it, it is simply not displayed on the page. No error message is thrown whatsoever in the console.
2. When trying to save a Display Page for scoped Web Content (either in `S1` or `S2`), this simply does not work. Once more, no error message is thrown, but the Page Display setting is simply not saved.

Is that normal, a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. I just tried this in the same Liferay version as yours and it seems to work for mee. Are you sure that you **approved** the web content? Also, do you have enough permissions to see the content?
2. This seems to be a bug: http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-28556